# Is an analytic solution possible?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, variational-calculus

I have this problem:  the parameters are T1, T2, R, Rthhot, Rthcold, and Z with feasible range >0.
The variables are Rth and Rload.

X and Y are functions of Rload and Rth given by the 2 equations:

```
0==-(T1 - X)/Rthhot + (X - Y)/Rth + S^2*X*(X - Y)/(R + Rload) + (-1)*0.5*S^2*Rload*(X - Y)^2/(R + Rload)^2

0==(Y - T2)/Rthcold - (X - Y)/Rth - S^2*Y*(X - Y)/(R + Rload) + (-1)*0.5*S^2*Rload*(X - Y)^2/(R + Rload)^2;
```

and S is a function of Rth  is given by:

```
0==S^2*Rth/R - Z;
```

I am trying to maximize power as a function of Rload and Rth:

```
power=S^2*(X - Y)^2*Rload/(R + Rload)^2;
```

I know how to solve it using either FindMaximum or Langrage multiplier if I assign numerical values to T1, T2, R, Rthhot, Rthcold, and Z. I'd like to know if it's possible to find an analytic solution if I leave T1, T2, R, Rthhot, Rthcold and Z as parameters.  Here is an example of my code:

```
T1 = 310; 
T2 = 300;  
Rthhot = 0.1; 
Rthcold = 6; 
R = 6; 
Z = 1/305 ;

Solve[{-(T1 - X)/Rthhot + (X - Y)/Rth + S^2*X*(X - Y)/(R + Rload) - 
0.5*S^2*Rload*(X - Y)^2/(R + Rload)^2 ==0, (Y - T2)/Rthcold - (X - Y)/Rth - S^2*Y*(X - Y)/(R + 
Rload) - 0.5*S^2*Rload*(X - Y)^2/(R + Rload)^2 == 0,
S^2*Rth/R - Z == 0, 
Grad[S^2*(X - Y)^2*Rload/(R + Rload)^2, {X, Y, Rload, Rth, S}] == 
lambda1 Grad[-(T1 - X)/Rthhot + (X - Y)/Rth + 
   S^2*X*(X - Y)/(R + Rload) - 
   0.5*S^2*Rload*(X - Y)^2/(R + Rload)^2, {X, Y, Rload, Rth, S}] +
lambda2 Grad[(Y - T2)/Rthcold - (X - Y)/Rth - 
   S^2*Y*(X - Y)/(R + Rload) - 
   0.5*S^2*Rload*(X - Y)^2/(R + Rload)^2, {X, Y, Rload, Rth, S}] +
lambda3 Grad[S^2*Rth/R - Z, {X, Y, Rload, Rth, S}]}]
```

And this code works fine.  But if I leave T1, T2, R, Rthhot, Rthcold, and Z as parameters it keeps running for a few days without finding a solution.

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't "work fine"! Please provide runnable Mathematica code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ulrich Neumann:  I added a screen shot of the code and results.

Comment: Community: I want to solve this problem without putting numerical values to T1, T2, R, Rthhot, Rthcold, and Z and get an analytic solution.  Or I want to know if getting an analytic solution is possible.  Thanks.

Comment: `0=` ... `Power=` ... this is incorrect syntax - you should use `==` and write `power` instead of `Power`  as that is a built in function.

Comment: flinty: yes, thank you for pointing out my mistakes.  I have made the corrections.